# Scalaj-Http: Using HttpRequest and getting back HttpResponse[string] - How can I access individual JSON elements of Respnse.Body?

Tags: json, scala, http, scala-collections

I want to count the language tags in Github repositories. I am using [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http)  for that.

```
val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=size:>=0").asString                   
val b = response.body,    
val c = response.code,    
val h = response.headers
```

I get back following:

```
b: String
c: Int
h: Map[String,String]
```

Body is returned as string. I want to now iterate over this body result to extract and further call a few nested URLs (you might get better idea of this if you see [GET result of URL mentioned above](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=size:%3E=0)).

Basically I want to call one of the URLs. How can I do this?

Comment: @dk14 and (at)chobeat were pointing you in the direction on 2 prior posts of yours

Comment: yes finally got, i had earlier chosen this path only. Since, i am new to sbt, was unable to get the dependencies right and finally started from scratch and successfully got scalaj-http set up. Its working now, just need few casting to maps to extract useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, where I have to work with json response, I used json4s and it path to extract the required field. Basically example code would be something like this

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val body= """ { "a" : { "b" : { "url" : "http://required.com" }}} """ 
val requiredUrl = (parse(body) \ "a" \"b" \ "url" ).values
```

If path matche point to more field in a list, you will get the results as list I think.